# Why is a DataRow recognized in one part of a method but not another (how can I dynamically add DataRows)?

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, dynamic, dotconnect

With this code:

```
OracleDataTable dt = PlatypusSchedData.GetAvailablePlatypi(); 
OracleDataTable outputDt = new OracleDataTable();

int iRows = 12;
while (iRows > 0)
{
    outputDt.Rows.Add(new DataRow()); // line 1
    //var dr = new DataRow();     // line 2a
    //outputDt.Rows.Add(dr);      // line 2b
    iRows -= 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i += 1) {
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
    int outputColumn = 0;
    if (i % 12 == 0 && i > 0) {
        outputColumn += 1; //2?
    }
    outputDt.Rows[i % 12][outputColumn] = dr[0];
    outputDt.Rows[i % 12][outputColumn + 1] = dr[1];
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = outputDt;
```

...I get this compile-time error using either line 1 (lines 2a and 2b commented out) or using lines 2a and 2b (with line 1 commented out):

*'System.Data.DataRow.DataRow(System.Data.DataRowBuilder)' is inaccessible due to its protection level*

This is baffling me because the DataRow in the for loop is tolerated. How can I add these DataRows to my OracleDataTable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The constructor for `DataRow` is marked as `protected internal`, and as such, you cannot construct it directly.

The correct code to get a new row for a `DataTable` is

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with `OracleDataTable` but i assume that it inherits from a normal `DataTable`.

You cannot create a `DataRow` directly because the constructor is [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Instead you must use one of the factory methods like [`DataTable.Rows.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.add.aspx) or [`DataTable.NewRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx). This ensures that the correct schema is applied on the new `DataRow` because it's determined from its `DataTable`.

So this should work:

```
while (iRows > 0)
{
    DataRow dr = outputDt.NewRow();
    // fill the fields of the row ...
    // add it to the DataTable:
    outputDt.Rows.Add(dr);
    iRows -= 1;
}
```